# ThinkingSphinx: dynamic indices on the SQL-backed indices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I am trying to use ThinkingSphinx (with SQL-backed indices) in my Rails 5 project.

I need some dynamic run-time indices to search over.

I have a `Message` model:

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User', :inverse_of => :messages
    belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User', :inverse_of => :messages
end
```

and its indexer:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :message, :with => :active_record, :delta => true do
    indexes text

    indexes sender.email, :as => :sender_email, :sortable => true

    indexes recipient.email, :as => :recipient_email, :sortable => true 

    indexes [sender.email, recipient.email], :as => :messager_email, :sortable => true

    has sender_id, created_at, updated_at

    has recipient_id

end
```

schema.rb:

```
  create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.text     "text"
    t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
    t.boolean  "read",         default: false
    t.boolean  "spam",         default: false
    t.boolean  "delta",        default: true,  null: false
    t.index ["recipient_id"], name: "index_messages_on_recipient_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["sender_id"], name: "index_messages_on_sender_id", using: :btree
  end
```

The problem is about so-called "dialogs". They don't exist in the database - they are determined at run-time. A dialog - that's a set of messages between 2 users, where each user may be either a sender or a receiver.

The task is to search through my dialogs and to find the dialog (dialog's messages) by the piece of the correspondent email. So complicated!

Here's my effort:

```
  conditions = {messager_email: search_email}

  with_current_user_dialogs = 

  "*, IF(sender_id = #{current_user.id} OR recipient_id = #{current_user.id}, 1, 0) AS current_user_dialogs"

  messages = Message.search search_email, conditions: conditions,

    select: with_current_user_dialogs,
    with: {'current_user_dialogs' => 1}
```

This is almost fine - but still not. This query correctly searches only within my dialog (within the messages I sent or received) and only within `:sender` and `:recipient` fields simultaneously (which is not best).

Say my email is "client1@example.com". Other emails are like "client2@example.com", "client3@example.com", "manager1@example.com".

The trouble is that when I search for "client1" - I get all the messages where I was either a sender or a receiver. But I should get nothing in response - I need to search only across my correspondents emails - not mine.

Even worse stuff happens also while querying "client" - I get back the correct correspondents with "client2@example.com", "client3@example.com" - but the result is spoiled with wrong "client1@example.com".

I need a way to choose at run-time - which index subset to search within.

I mean this condition is not enough for me:

```
indexes [sender.email, recipient.email], :as => :messager_email, :sortable => true
```

It searches (for "client") within **all** the sender.email and **all** the recipient.email at once.

But I need to dynamically choose like: "search **only** within `sender.email` values conforming to `if sender.id != current_user.id`" OR "search **only** within `recipient.email` conforming to `if recipient.id != current_user.id`" (because I can be as a sender as a receiver).

That's what I call a "dynamic index".

How to do that? Such "dynamic index" surely would depend on the current `current_user` value - so it will be different for the different users - even on the same total messages set.

It is clear that I can't apply whatever **post-search** cut-offs (what to cut off?) - I need to somehow limitate the search itself.

I tried to search over some scope - but got the error that "searching is impossible over scopes" - something like that.

Maybe I should use the real-time indexing instead of the SQL-backed indexing?

Sorry for the complexity of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Would the following work?

```
other = User.find_by :email => search_email
with_current_user_dialogs = "*, IF((sender_id = #{current_user.id} AND recipient_id = #{other.id}) OR (recipient_id = #{current_user.id} AND sender_id = #{other.id}), 1, 0) AS current_user_dialogs"
```

Or do you need partial matches on the searched email address?

**[EDIT]**

Okay, from the discussion in the comments below, it's clear that the field data is critical. While you can construct a search query that uses both fields and attributes, you can't have logic in the query that combines the two. That is, you can't say: "Search field 'x' when attribute 'i' is 1, otherwise search field 'y'."

The only way I can possibly see this working is if you're using fields for both parts of the logic. Perhaps something like the following:

```
current_user_email = "\"" + current_user.email + "\""

Message.search(
  "(@sender_email #{current_user_email} @recipient_email #{search_email}) | (@sender_email #{search_email} @recipient_email #{current_user_email})"
)
```

Comment: I need a "live search" - as the user types in a search-word (a letter by letter), the search result  narrows immediately. So I need a search engine - simply ActiveRecord is not enough.

Comment: May I have some models with the real-time index and some with the SQL-backed index **at once**? Then what should I apply - `rake ts:regenerate` or `rake ts:rebuild`?

Comment: You can't currently mix-and-match both SQL-backed and real-time backed indices, I'm afraid.

Comment: Please write this fact down into your docs section "Common Questions and Issues".

Comment: Can you add to your SQL-backed indices the possibility to search over scopes? That would solve my problem - without switching to (unwanted) real-time indices.

Comment: You can't use ActiveRecord scopes for SphinxQL searches, as ActiveRecord interacts with the database, and SphinxQL with Sphinx. For indexing data for SQL-backed indices, scopes aren't available, but you can limit data via the `where` method: http://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/indexing.html#conditions - and for real-time indices, scopes can be used within the `scope` block: http://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/real_time.html

Comment: But just to be clear: it sounds like the issue you're dealing with is for _searching_. The distinction between SQL-backed and real-time is only for the indexing/processing of data into Sphinx. Searching in both cases happens through the SphinxQL query language.

Comment: How can I supply a param at run-time into an index (SQL-backed or real-time)? I need to provide `current_user.id` into the "index" statement - but how? I didn't find this even for real-time indices.

Comment: You can't dynamically insert data into a Sphinx index file as a temporary thing. It's not technically possible, and that would affect all concurrent queries. The dynamic elements must be done within the search query.

Comment: You mean that SphinxQL is capable to dynamically conditionally (based on the current `current_user.id` value) exclude some parts of the original index from the "searching base" at the run-time? This could be an answer to my original question. If so, I could even stick to the SQL-backed indices (which I prefer).

Comment: I edited my answer earlier with a potential solution. But your initial attempt is also an accurate approach to having `current_user` or any other piece of data influence the behaviour of a search query.

Comment: Looks like it works eventually. Thanks a lot! Is this a SphinxQL syntax? Is it described somewhere in http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/sphinxql-reference.html ? I was about to switch to the ordinary AR find. :)

Comment: Is is mentioned there, but you've got to hunt for it. The `MATCH` function in the `WHERE` clause takes a full-text search query that follows the extended query syntax: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax - which, in Thinking Sphinx, is the combination of the initial string argument, plus any `:conditions`.